# Animation: Move ImageButton horizontal and vertical

Tags: android, animation, move, imagebutton

My ImageButton is moving horizontal correctly. But I want move both horizontal and vertical.
And then repeate.

**move.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillBefore="true"
android:repeatMode="reset">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="70%p"
    android:duration="2000" />

</set>
```

**hand_motion.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#aa000000"
android:id="@+id/VHandLevel">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/ibtnHandLevel"
    android:background="@drawable/hand1"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I add this line in move.xml:

```
android:toYDelta="70%p"
```

It will move diagonally. But I want first move horizontally and then vertical also will repeat.

Some code of **MainActivity.java**

```
ImageButton iBtnHelp = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ibtnHandLevel);
    Animation animation1 =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);
    animation1.setRepeatCount(20);
    iBtnHelp.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating an instance of the Animation programmatically like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);
```

then you can set the counter to repeat the same animation as many times
as you want:

```
animation.setRepeatCount(10);
```